# Pandas: evaluate two dataframes against each other

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

Let's imagine a remember/recall game. There are rooms with a table full of chocolate and other stuff. You have 20seconds to look at each table. Later on you are asked what you've seen. This gives two datasets. One with the configuration of the tables and another one of what you can remember. The task is to evaluate which items you have recalled correctly and which one's you can not remember. In this task we don't care about the brand of the product. Just the type.

[image]

Here's a sample configuration for two rooms.

```
config = [
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Mars'},
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Mars'},
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Milka'},
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'nuts', 'brand': 'Bahlsen'},
        {'room': 'room2', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Mars'},
        {'room': 'room2', 'kind': 'nuts', 'brand': 'Ültje'},
        {'room': 'room2', 'kind': 'nuts', 'brand': 'Bahlsen'}
        ]

import pandas as pd
df_config = pd.DataFrame(config).sort_values(['room'])
df_config
```

Now you got 20second to memorize the times. Afterwards you are asked what you've seen. Here's what you remember:

```
recall = [
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate'},
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate'},
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'nuts'},
        {'room': 'room2', 'kind': 'nuts'}
        ]

import pandas as pd
df_recall = pd.DataFrame(recall).sort_values(['room'])
df_recall
```

Obviously you've seen two chocolate bars in room 1 thus you missed the third one. For room 2 you missed the second bag of nuts. So, the evaluation result would be somewhat like this:

```
correct = [
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Mars', 'eval': 'correct'}, # first chocolate room1
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Mars', 'eval': 'correct'}, # second chocolate room1
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'nuts', 'brand': 'Bahlsen', 'eval': 'correct'}, # first nuts room1
        {'room': 'room2', 'kind': 'nuts', 'brand': 'Ültje', 'eval': 'correct'}, # first nuts room2
        ]

incorrect = [
        {'room': 'room1', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Milka', 'eval': 'incorrect'}, # third chocolate room1 not recalled
        {'room': 'room2', 'kind': 'chocolate', 'brand': 'Mars', 'eval': 'incorrect'}, # first chocolate room2 not recalled
        {'room': 'room2', 'kind': 'nuts', 'brand': 'Bahlsen', 'eval': 'incorrect'} # second nuts room2 not recalled
        ]
```

I was thinking to merge both datasets based on the room and then group by the room and evaluate each group. Either by **iterating over the group** or using **df.groupy(['room']).apply(my_function)**. The problem is, that the merge creates a quite huge group for each room and I'm not sure how to evaluate this.

```
df = pd.merge(df_config, df_recall, on='room', suffixes=('', '_recall'))
```

Any idea is welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need helper columns for unique values per `rooms` and `kind` by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). Then add column to parameter `on` and specify left join:

```
df_config['g'] = df_config.groupby(['room','kind']).cumcount()
df_recall['g'] = df_recall.groupby(['room','kind']).cumcount()

df = pd.merge(df_config, df_recall, on=['room', 'g'], suffixes=('', '_recall'), how='left')
print (df)
     brand       kind   room  g kind_recall
0     Mars  chocolate  room1  0   chocolate
1     Mars  chocolate  room1  0        nuts
2     Mars  chocolate  room1  1   chocolate
3    Milka  chocolate  room1  2         NaN
4  Bahlsen       nuts  room1  0   chocolate
5  Bahlsen       nuts  room1  0        nuts
6     Mars  chocolate  room2  0        nuts
7    Ültje       nuts  room2  0        nuts
8  Bahlsen       nuts  room2  1         NaN
```

Comment: And then finally just evaluate kind vs. kind_recall? The problem in your solution is that for room1 the Bahlsen nuts are NaN in the kind_recall column even though the person has correctly remembered them.

Comment: What about `df_config.groupby(['room', 'type']).cumcount()` ?

Comment: One more thing: for room2 the first row says chocolate vs. nuts. But actually the chocolate should be NaN since the guy hasn't seen any chocolate in room2 but just nuts. A way to solve that would be to join the df_recall with all unique value-kinds of df_config. Then nuts would be 1 and chocolate would 0 and the merge would yield another result. But how to do that?

Comment: I changed your code a bit. First I created a copy of the df_recall.kind column and then added the 'kind' column to the merge that is now ['room', 'g', 'kind']. Thus the evaluation of the merge-result is easier since it is automatically ordered/grouped by product kinds. The evaluation is: if row['kind'] == row['kind_seen']:
        return 'correct'
    elif row['kind_seen'] is np.NaN:
        return 'missed'
    elif row['kind'] != row['kind_seen']:
        return 'ignore'